# Scons (Build System) Variables : load config file with custom/unknown values

Tags: variables, config, scons

I have a trouble with Scons.Variables. I want to use config files with custom keys and values. My idea to load config files with keys and values and use it with SubstFile method. 
For example (rough code) :

```
vars = Variables('templateValues.conf')
vars_dict = vars.UnknownVariables().keys() # bad code, need something to convert vars to Python dictionary
env.Substfile('myconfig.cfg.in', SUBST_DICT = vars_dict)
```

But vars.UnknownVariables() return empty list.
My test template file :

```
version = 105
mode = 'release'
source = 'database'
emulate = 'no'
```

And vars.UknownVariables() called :

```
vars = Variables('templateValues.conf')
print vars.UnknownVariables().keys()
# []
```

May be somebody try to implement something like this and can give some advances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not found neeeded tools in Scons, but Python is great (i newbie in python now, few days studing only).

Google give me some useful links, such as [SimpleConfigParser](http://www.decalage.info/en/python/configparser) (i use method from  CustomParser)

Implement it is very easy and i got what i need :

```
Import('env')
templVars = parse_config('template.conf')
varEnv = env.Clone(tools = ['textfile', 'default'])
varEnv.Substfile('config.cfg.in', SUBST_DICT = templVars)
```

Content of config.cfg.in file :

```
this is simple text with template values
Version is %version%
Build mode is %mode%

Emulator mode %emulate%

Thanks for using Avina !
```

Content of template.conf file :

```
%version% = 105
%mode% = 'test1'
%source% = 'database'
%emulate% = 'no'
```

And result file :

```
this is simple text with template values
Version is 105
Build mode is 'test1'

Emulator mode 'no'

Thanks for using Avina !
```